# Remove the beginning of a line in a file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file having this format:

```
21:26:54.21 PT  disconnected
21:26:56.18 CC1 received TCMTM
21:26:56.18 CC2 received TCMTM
21:26:56.18 TFT received TCMTM
21:26:56.18 FEC received TCMTM
```

I want to remove the first part of each line (21:26:54.21), I've tried this:

```
sed "s/^[:digit:]*[:space:]//"  file.log
```

But it doesn't work, I am getting the same output as the entry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `cut`:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f2- file
PT  disconnected
CC1 received TCMTM
CC2 received TCMTM
TFT received TCMTM
FEC received TCMTM
```

*Sets the space as delimiter and print from field 2 up to the last one (`f2-`).*

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '{$1=""}1' file  ## leading space :(
 PT disconnected
 CC1 received TCMTM
 CC2 received TCMTM
 TFT received TCMTM
 FEC received TCMTM
```

*Sets the first field as empty.*

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF; i++) $i=$(i+1); NF=NF-1}1' file
PT disconnected
CC1 received TCMTM
CC2 received TCMTM
TFT received TCMTM
FEC received TCMTM
```

*It decreases the field number by one, moving each one to the previous (hence, first is deleted).*

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^[^ ]* //g' file
PT  disconnected
CC1 received TCMTM
CC2 received TCMTM
TFT received TCMTM
FEC received TCMTM
```

*Deletes everything from the beginning of the line up to the first space.*

or based on your `sed`:

```
$ sed "s/^[0-9:.]* //g" file
PT  disconnected
CC1 received TCMTM
CC2 received TCMTM
TFT received TCMTM
FEC received TCMTM
```

*Deletes all chars `0-9` or `:` or `.` from the beginning of the line up to the first space.*

Comment: Good to read that, @georgiana_e. Note I also posted a version based on your `sed` attempt.

Comment: Yes, @cbuckley I indicate it in the output. Updated with a better aproach - Jotne's is better, using `sub`.

Comment: @fedorqui I know, I was just being nit-picky about it being a leading space and not a trailing space :-)

Comment: Oooops you are right, @cbuckley, I am learning both programming and English in this site :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{$1=x;sub(/^ /,x)}1' file
PT disconnected
CC1 received TCMTM
CC2 received TCMTM
TFT received TCMTM
FEC received TCMTM
```

---

Another version

```
awk '{sub(/^[0-9:.]+ /,x)}1' file
```

---

And another

```
awk '{sub(/[^ ]* /,x)}1' file
```

Comment: +1 for the awk approach... I don't really understand how the `{$1=x;sub(/^ /,x)}` works, could you explain it?

Comment: Set filed `$1=x` , since `x` is nothing, set `$1` to nothing. You can use `$1=""` instead.  `sub(/^ /,x)` replace one blank at beginning  og line with nothing (`x`)

Comment: Oh, nice. It was the call to `x` in `sub()` that was confusing me. So  with `{$1="";sub(/^ /,"")}1` it would be somehow more explicit what you are doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/^[0-9:.]* *//' file.log
```

Output:

```
PT  disconnected
CC1 received TCMTM
CC2 received TCMTM
TFT received TCMTM
FEC received TCMTM
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to missing the `:` and `.` that need to be matched in the timestamp, you have a slight error in how you are using the character classes:

```
sed "s/^[[:digit:]:.]*[[:space:]]//" file.log
```

A character class such as `[:digit:]` is only valid inside `[...]`, so you would need

```
s/^[[:digit:]]*
```

to match zero or more digits at the beginning of the line. You still need to match `:` or `.` as well, so add them to the `[...]` as well:

```
s/^[[:digit:].:]*
```

Think of `[:digit:]` as a replacement for `0-9`, not `[0-9]`. You could write the above with

```
s/^[0-9.:]*
```

which would match the digits 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, but not any other characters that might be considered digits in your current locale.